# Indian kids fantasy show incorporating main actor recasting as plot point

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching this Hindi kid show on Doordarshan (DD1) in the 90s.

**Genres:** Fantasy kids

**Plot:** One boy and girl, probably friends but can be siblings. Found a dark place with a box of colors and a magical entity who is an old looking guy who helps them with their day to day issue in magical ways and tricks. It was more episodic with the problem of the day story arc. He tells kids to apply these watercolors on their face and they either transform or do something magical.

**Specific episode story:** One of the kids got injured before the exam and was not able to write. This old magical guy makes their pen magically write whatever the kid thinks about writing.

**Casting changes:** Main lead girl child leaves the show and they make a 2 episode arc that it is part of the magical mishap where the girl was given a new face and she likes it so much that she asked that old guy to make everyone remember her as her new face only.

**Broadcast year:** Must be the mid to late 90s

**Language:** Hindi

It was full of the message-oriented episodes like hard-working, don't cheat, don't be greedy etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging more I found it myself, the show name is [The Magic Make-Up Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Make-Up_Box)
. Even the [plot](https://nettv4u.com/about/Hindi/tv-serials/the-magic-make-up-box) matches and able to watch some clips from YouTube to verify. And found screencaps too for the third main lead:

[image][image]

After this type of colouring process, they used to transform.

The main child actress was Shweta Basu Prasad who I remember got recast later but not able to find that information for her now.